# Database for Sencha Touch + Phonegap Application

Tags: cordova, ios8, sencha-touch-2, local-storage, phonegap-build

Hi currently i'm using LocalStorage in my Sencha Touch + Phonegap in my application and loaded with more than 4000+ records get from WCF Rest . During development mode i have no problem running it in Google Chrome but when i packaged it and installed in iOS8 device my application crashes.

Below is the total localStorage lenght in console:

```
>JSON.stringify(localStorage).length
> 2917665
```

**Model:**

```
Ext.define("QualityAudit.model.DefectMatrix", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        identifier: { type: 'uuid', isUnique: true },
        fields: [
                { name: "DefectMatrixID", type: "integer" },
                { name: "CustomerID", type: "integer" },
                { name: "CustomerName", type: "string" },
                { name: "DefectType", type: "integer" },
                { name: "DefectTypeName", type: "string" },
                { name: "Reference", type: "string" },
                { name: "Section", type: "string" },
                { name: "DefectDescription", type: "string" },
                { name: "SeverityID", type: "integer" },
                { name: "SeverityName", type: "string" },
                { name: "IsActive", type: "bool" },
                { name: "CreatedBy", type: "string" },
                { name: "CreatedDate", type: 'date', dateFormat: 'MS' }
        ]
    }
});
```

**Store:**

```
 defectSync: function (counter, totRecords, callback) {
    var me = this;
    if (counter == undefined)
        counter = 0;


    //load defect matrix local local storage

    var defectsLocalStore = Ext.getStore('DefectMatrix');
    defectsLocalStore.load();

        var defectssurl = window.REST_DMGetListAllPaging + counter;
        QualityAudit.util.Proxy.doAjaxCall(defectssurl, '',
        function (response) {

            var data = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText); //encode Json List


            defectsLocalStore.load({
                callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                    Ext.Array.each(data, function (record) {
                        counter++;
                        record.dirty = true;
                        defectsLocalStore.add(record);
                        defectsLocalStore.sync();
                    });

                    console.log('DECFECT DATA AFTER SYNC: ' + defectsLocalStore.getData().length);

                    //Check if all records  loaded on local storage is equail to total defect rows then complete
                    if (defectsLocalStore.getData().length >= totRecords) {
                        console.log('defect loading successfull');
                        callback();
                    } else {
                        //Trigger again until condition is met
                        me.defectSync(counter, totRecords, callback);
                    }

                },
                scope: this
            });


        },
        function (response) {
            defectsLocalStore.load();
            callback(0);
        });

}
```

Does anyone tried using webSQL or SQLlite in your projects? I cant find any good sample on this.

Any help and suggestions is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use SQLite in nearly every of my project. IMHO the best plugin is [Cordova/PhoneGap SQLitePlugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin).

You find some examples on the page, how to use the plugin and how to use SQLite in cordova.

Comment: Hi @Joerg do you still use sencha store if you already using sqlite ?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I don't use sencha store.

Comment: Can you give any sample code in populating Sencha touch list view? Thanks

Comment: No, I can't. I don't use sencha and I wrote my own listview. The reason is simple: I have a lot of records in my apps and the listviews I found are slow. So, I wrote one, where only the neccessary entries are in the view.

Comment: Oh okay @Joerg Thanks a lot ;D Im currently using Secha Touch + Phonegap for my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use store with proxy: 'sql', it will create local database using WebSQL.
[sql proxy Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Sql)